# How to use 'OR' in regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want to have a regular expression that accepts these forms :

> 23456KW33C3
>
> 23456KW33
>
> 23456K
>
> 23456
>
> 23456W33C3
>
> 23456W33

I wrote these two regex

```
/(?i)^2\d{4}K?(M|(W33)(C3)?)?$/i

/(?i)^2\d{4}K?(M|(W33)|(W33C3))?$/i
```

They accepts all forms but not `23456KW33C3` !!!

I use it in if expression :

```
if (preg_match('/(?i)^2\d{4}K?(M|(W33)(C3)?)?$/i' ,$text))
```

What's wrong with them ?

Comment: They [match1](https://regex101.com/r/Adj0ob/3) and  [match2](https://regex101.com/r/Adj0ob/2), but you might simplify it to `^2\d{4}K?(?:M|W33(?:C3)?)?` https://regex101.com/r/Adj0ob/1

Comment: yes, they match when i test it but if statement doesnt execute by `23456KW33C3` !!!

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/CS9i3 and https://3v4l.org/n04q0 Are you sure there are no characters in front or after the text?

Comment: Your regexps work. Please provide a minimal complete verifiable example to repro your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You expression works fine, you might just want to remove the start and end chars and it would pass `23456KW33C3` too.

```
2\d{4}k?(m|(w33)(c3)?)?
```

[This link](https://regex101.com/r/SaTQbT/1) helps you to modify/update your expressions as you wish.

[image]

I'm not quite sure what you would like to match. You might want to simplify your expression and reduce the restrictions that it has.

---

If you wish to write your expressions with OR, [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/5Rf04Z/1) shows how you might want to do so:

```
2\d{4}(k|)|(m|w33)|(c3)
```

You can add them in between the capturing groups that you have, to swipe your desired outputs from left to right. Then, if you wanted, after that you can add more boundaries.

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

This [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) helps you to visualize your expressions:

[image]